# Knex + Postgresql + node - how to call postgresql functions for selected columns

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

I want to check record exists or not in postgresql and need result in boolean.

**NOTE :** I know there are simple ways with if else check but what I want is the representation in knex for the query I listed. I also know this is complex but just wants to learn.

I know the query, You can see here below,

```
select exists(select 1 from test where id = XYZ);
```

How can I write this postgresql query with knex?

I tried this way but it is not working.

```
knex.raw(`SELECT exists(${knex(TABLE_NAME).where(CONDITIONS).select('1').toString()})`)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do the boolean conversion in DB side (there won't be any performance difference):

```
knex('test').select('id').where('id', 'XYZ').then(results => results.length > 0);
```

this also works if you really prefer to `select 1` instead of `id`:

```
knex('test').select(knex.raw('1')).where('id', 'XYZ').then(results => results.length > 0);
```

Tim's answer is also good and gives more exactly the thing you were trying to do, but it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: This is probably the best answer.  The code from the GitHub link has to do a lot of dancing to simulate an exists query.

Comment: I know this all simple ways but I want to know the way in knex for the listed query.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I'll edit the question to match the thing you wanted to ask

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the code below from [this useful GitHub Knex post](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/949):

```
var inner = knex('test').where('id', 'XYZ').limit(1);
var clause = knex.raw(inner).wrap('exists (', ') as result');
knex('test').select(clause).limit(1).then(...);
```

I think this should correspond to the following SQL code:

```
select exists (select * from test where id = 'XYZ' limit 1) as result
from test
limit 1;
```

The outer query on `test` is superfluous, and not needed, but I don't know of a way, other than perhaps a raw query, to not run a query against a table in Knex.  The `LIMIT` statement just means it will return a single value.